# unable to find "attribute" field in "ClassBreaksRenderer " class

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, feature-layer

I am trying to run [Map ServerLayer sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html#/Based_on_MapServer_layer/01nq0000000r000000/) given on arcgis resource center.When I pasted the code in my FlashBuilder 4.6 then it is showing error on this line `<esri:ClassBreaksRenderer attribute="POP2000">` . 
Error is

```
Multiple markers at this line:
-Cannot resolve attribute 'attribute' for component type com.esri.ags.renderers.ClassBreaksRenderer.
-ClassBreaksRenderer
-1 changed line
```

It means it is not recognizing the `attribute` field of `esri:ClassBreaksRenderer`. I am unable to understand the reason?Any suggestions?

**Note:** I am using `flex4.6.0` and latest version of arcgis API which is `agslib-3.3-2013-04-24.swc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*The attribute, attribute2, attribute3, and attributeDelimiter properties that were deprecated at 2.5 have been removed at 3.0. **Use field**, field2, field3, and fieldDelimiter **instead***."

From the What's New document at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-api/concepts/index.html#//017p0000000w000000

Note that your link goes to the 2.x API documentation.  If you are using the 3.x API, you should be looking at the 3.x pages: http://links.esri.com/flex always points to the latest version.

Comment: Its very bad that I can't give you up vote :( Anyway Awesome man awesome :)